# Android Media Player Streaming issue on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm streaming the audio file (.mp3) from internet with Android Media Player.

It works quite well except Samsung Devices. As far as I see, it doesn't stream the audio but tries to download. It sometimes pushes Media Player Error (1 -1004). Nothing is getting played.

I also tried to redirect the Application to the Media Player with URL of audio file, it goes to Music Player application, indicating "Preparing..." for a while, but then It shows the message "sorry, player does not support this type of audio" with Toast.

Anybody else had the same error before ? Any advise to find a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs in native sound libraries on Samsung Galaxy S2 for instance ([look here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/pAv5UfQgtH4)). I had those problems (random crashes / freezes) and solved it by using OpenSL library for that specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was searching on internet for a while to figure out how OpenSL library works. I also found another API called AudioTrack API in Android. I don't know which one is more suitable and easier to implement. I basically need to stream the audio from the server. any suggestion, if you already tried both of them ?

Comment: I haven't used `AudioTack` because I had only few sounds I wanted to be played locally, not using any streaming. Library I found was OpenSL-SoundPool (http://code.google.com/p/opensl-soundpool/) which fit me perfecty, because SoundPool was the class I used before, but with problems described above. Not sure if this can help, you, if you want streaming, though...

Comment: Instead of Streaming the file my own, I decided to download file then play it from directory for Samsung devices except Google branded Samsung devices.